# How to see the storage usage in NEAR protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

I learned that data storage on NEAR protocol requires to stake NEAR tokens. Is there a way to monitor the total amount of data stored on chain? Didn't find it on NEAR Explorer (or perhaps didn't look at the right place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The increase/decrease in storage use automatically locks some of the tokens on the account. Explorer displays "STORAGE USED" on the account details page ([example](https://explorer.near.org/accounts/frol.near)). mainnet is configured (see [`EXPERIMENTAL_protocol_config` JSON RPC method](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/protocol#protocol-config) for other config options) to have `"storage_amount_per_byte": "100000000000000000000"`, which means that 100kb of data (smart contract code, smart contract state, account access keys, and profile data [liquid balance, locked balance, account id]) locks 1 NEAR on your account (so you just cannot transfer/spend those tokens unless you remove something from the storage).